# How to output a string in a excel/google-spreadsheet function?

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I'm using the if statement to check whether a cell is a number. If yes, just return the original number, else, return the string 'Not a number'. However, I got some troubles while I was outputting the string 'Not a number'. Following are the function I'm using, how could I modify it?

```
=if(isnumber(A1), A1, 'Not a number')
```

It works while A1 is a number but fails while it's not a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing double quotes.

Try this

```
=if(isnumber(A1), A1,"Not a number")
```

Comment: don't he need semicolons as well?